# Remove debug methods on final compile

Tags: java, maven, logging, system.out

I often need debug messages for programming. Everytime before I release a new version, I have to remove them, and add them back after compiling everything. Is there a way to do ignore specific method calls when compiling with maven?

For example, if the code looks like:

```
int i = 10;

@Debug System.out.println(i);

doSomething(i);
```

it would remove everything tagged with @Debug when I want to compile a final version.

Comment: kotlin has inline method, maybe you can comment out the inlined method body in the release build. I hope Java could have 
 something like this……

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An annotation cannot be specified in the body of a method

Here are the possible use :

```
    /** Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration */
    TYPE,

    /** Field declaration (includes enum constants) */
    FIELD,

    /** Method declaration */
    METHOD,

    /** Formal parameter declaration */
    PARAMETER,

    /** Constructor declaration */
    CONSTRUCTOR,

    /** Local variable declaration */
    LOCAL_VARIABLE,

    /** Annotation type declaration */
    ANNOTATION_TYPE,

    /** Package declaration */
    PACKAGE,

    /**
     * Type parameter declaration
     *
     * @since 1.8
     */
    TYPE_PARAMETER,

    /**
     * Use of a type
     *
     * @since 1.8
     */
    TYPE_USE
```

So you cannot use annotation in this way.

Besides, the Maven build execution should not change the behavior of your classes.
You should avoid creating variation in the built component. That could create surprise in no development environments.

If you want to exclude debugging information in some specific environments, use  logging mechanisms (Log4j or Logback for example) instead of using the standard output (`System.out.println`) that is not designed to write debugging information.

During development, use a logging configuration that enables the debug level for the classes belonging to a specific package and in no development environments, use a logging configuration that disables the debug level for these same classes.

Answer (score 1):

In Java production code it is preferable to use a logger instead of System.out

This has the benefit of allowing you to configure the required log level.

I.e debug for local testing and info (or error) for release.

Comment: Additionally, you can configure where the messages are logged to (console, file, database, etc).